# jquery blankout / grayout the page where dialog box is showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

How can I blankout the page where I show the dialog box.
below is my code
HTML:

```
<style>
.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog-content {
 border:1px solid #cde68c;
 border-bottom:0px;
 background-color: white !important;
 color: #333;
 font: 12px/180% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
 display:none;
}
#ui-dialog-title-dialog {
 color: yellow !important;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
 border:1px solid #cde68c;
 border-top:0px;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}

</style>
        <div id="dialog">
            <p><span id="emailNotice"></span></p>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j('#dialog').dialog('open');
    $j('#emailNotice').html('show some notice text abcd');  

    $j('#dialog').dialog({
        modal:true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $j(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                className: 'cancelButtonClass',
                $j(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**TRIED**

```
<style>
.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog-content {
 border:1px solid #cde68c;
 background-color: white !important;
 color: #333;
 line-height: 180%;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
 display:none;
}
#ui-dialog-title-dialog {
 color: yellow !important;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
 border:1px solid #cde68c;
 border-top:0px;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}

ui-widget-overlay { 
    background: #aaaaaa url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    opacity: 50;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=50);  
}
</style>
```

**ALSO TRIED**

```
$j('#dialog').dialog('open');
                 $j("#dialog").dialog("widget")
                 .next(".ui-widget-overlay")
                 .css("background", "#f00ba2");
....
....
```

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean by 'blank out' but there is a css class that jquery ui dialog assigns to the overlay for the dialog, ui-widget-overlay, when you have modal set to true. it can be modified to change the style of the overlay div

Comment: modla is set to true but it just doesnt work

Comment: is there anything under the dialog at all? can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Autolycus Can you paste the entire '<head>' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the default jQueryUI class like this:

```
.ui-widget-overlay { 
    background: #aaaaaa url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
    opacity: 100 !important;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=100) !important;  
}
```

Just change the color and opacity to what you like and this will be applied to the page when the modal opens.

If the `!important` don't work you have an issue with your setup.

Maybe you don't have jQueryUI fully functional. Make sure you have both the jQueryUI js and css files linked/referenced in your  element.

Comment: where at? where do I do this? I found exact same on google too but wasnt sure where to implement it according to my code

Comment: Add it to your embedded stylesheet

Comment: It is in the jqueryui stylesheet.